# How can I find a page based upon URL in Expression Engine?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm a total noob at EE.  We are using version 1.6.6 and I need to make a change to the following page:

http://www.mysite.com/contact/thanks

Is there a simple way of searching your site in EE to find a page that you know exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities but most likely is that you have a template group called "contact" and within that template group you have a template called "thanks".

So, in your EE control panel go to the "templates" tab and then look for the template group called "contact" on the left.  Then on the right you should see a list of templates.  Hopefully there is one called "thanks".

Comment: Yup.  That did it.  But is there a good way to search for a word or phrase across the entire site?

Comment: If you want to search within your templates, there is a search box at the bottom left of the Template Management interface.  If you want to search in the weblog entries, you can search in the Edit interface.